# Use AnimatedList inside a StreamBuilder

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder, flutter-animatedlist

I am building a chat app with firebase and I am currently storing each message as a document inside a collection in firebase. I use a StreamBuilder to get the latest messages and display them. I want to add an animation when a new message is received and sent. I have tried using an Animatedlist, however, I don't get how to make it work with a StreamBuilder. As far as I understand I would have to call the *insertItem* function each time a new message is added. Is there a smarter way to do it? Or how would this be implemented?

This is what I have so far:

````
class Message {
  final String uid;
  final String message;
  final Timestamp timestamp;

  Message({this.uid, this.timestamp, this.message});
}

class MessagesWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final String receiver;
  MessagesWidget({@required this.receiver});

  @override
  _MessagesWidgetState createState() => _MessagesWidgetState();
}

class _MessagesWidgetState extends State<MessagesWidget>{
  final GlobalKey<AnimatedListState> _listKey = GlobalKey<AnimatedListState>();

  Tween<Offset> _offset = Tween(begin: Offset(1,0), end: Offset(0,0));

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = Provider.of<User>(context);
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: StreamBuilder<List<Message>>(
                stream: DatabaseService(uid: user.uid).getMessages(widget.receiver),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                    case ConnectionState.waiting:
                      return Loading();
                    default:
                      final messages = snapshot.data;
                      return messages.isEmpty
                          ? SayHi(userID: widget.receiver,)
                          : AnimatedList(
                              key: _listKey,
                              physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                              reverse: true,
                              initialItemCount: messages.length,
                              itemBuilder: (context, index, animation) {
                                final message = messages[index];
                                return SlideTransition(
                                    position: animation.drive(_offset),
                                    child: MessageWidget(
                                    message: message,
                                    userID: widget.receiver,
                                    isCurrentUser: message.uid == user.uid,
                                  ),
                                );
                              },
                            );
                  }
                }),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 10,
          ),
          NewMessage(
            receiver: widget.receiver,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}```
````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can update your widget's `State` to this below:

```dart
class _MessagesWidgetState extends State<MessagesWidget> {
  final GlobalKey<AnimatedListState> _listKey = GlobalKey<AnimatedListState>();

  Tween<Offset> _offset = Tween(begin: Offset(1, 0), end: Offset(0, 0));

  Stream<List<Message>> stream;

  List<Message> currentMessageList = [];

  User user;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    user = Provider.of<User>(context, listen: false);

    stream = DatabaseService(uid: user.uid).getMessages(widget.receiver);

    stream.listen((newMessages) {
      final List<Message> messageList = newMessages;

      if (_listKey.currentState != null &&
          _listKey.currentState.widget.initialItemCount < messageList.length) {
        List<Message> updateList =
            messageList.where((e) => !currentMessageList.contains(e)).toList();

        for (var update in updateList) {
          final int updateIndex = messageList.indexOf(update);
          _listKey.currentState.insertItem(updateIndex);
        }
      }

      currentMessageList = messageList;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: StreamBuilder<List<Message>>(
                stream: stream,
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                    case ConnectionState.waiting:
                      return Loading();
                    default:
                      final messages = snapshot.data;
                      return messages.isEmpty
                          ? SayHi(
                              userID: widget.receiver,
                            )
                          : AnimatedList(
                              key: _listKey,
                              physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                              reverse: true,
                              initialItemCount: messages.length,
                              itemBuilder: (context, index, animation) {
                                final message = messages[index];
                                return SlideTransition(
                                  position: animation.drive(_offset),
                                  child: MessageWidget(
                                    message: message,
                                    userID: widget.receiver,
                                    isCurrentUser: message.uid == user.uid,
                                  ),
                                );
                              },
                            );
                  }
                }),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 10,
          ),
          NewMessage(
            receiver: widget.receiver,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Also, update your `Message` class to the code below:

```dart
// Using the equatable package, remember to add it to your pubspec.yaml file
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';

class Message extends Equatable{
  final String uid;
  final String message;
  final Timestamp timestamp;

  Message({this.uid, this.timestamp, this.message});

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [uid, message, timestamp];
}
```

**Explanation:**

The `State` code above does the following:

1. It stores the current messages in a list `currentMessageList` outside the build method
2. It listens to the stream to get new messages and compares the new list with the previous one in `currentMessageList`.
3. It gets the difference between both lists and loops through to update the `AnimatedList` widget at the specific index `updateIndex`.

The `Message` code above does the following:

- It overrides the `==` operator and the object `hashcode` to allow the check in this line: `List<Message> updateList = messageList.where((e) => !currentMessageList.contains(e)).toList();` work as intended. [Without overriding these getters, the check would fail as two different `Message` objects with the same values would not be equivalent].
- It uses the [equatable](https://pub.dev/packages/equatable) package to avoid boiler-plate.

Comment: Thanks! That approach seems to work. However, for some reason, the whole list is animated instead of just a single new message. Would you happen to have any idea how to change that? Really appreciate your detailed answer.

Comment: When you say "the whole list is animated", does this refer to when the screen opens for the first time or when you add a new document to the collection? Also, please include a screen recording as that'll help with debugging this.

Comment: I meant to say that the whole list of messages are animated, not just the one being added. It's because of this line of code: `List<Message> updateList = (messageList.where((e) => !currentMessageList.contains(e))).toList();` The updateList always contains all the elements of the stream which means that they get inserted to the animated list and therefore all elements are animated. I don't know how to insert a video, however, it basically just makes the whole list animate when a new message I added.

Comment: Do you have this line : `currentMessageList = messageList;` in your initState in the stream listener?

Comment: Yes, I do. I copied the code you sent directly only changing the two occurrences of 'List<String>' to also be 'List<Message>' otherwise the code is identical. Printing the length of updateList and also printing the updateIndex inside the update loop gives: 26,0,1...25 which means that it updates the whole list.

Comment: Okay. Can you print `messageList` and `updateList` at the line just before this if statement: ` if (_listKey.currentState != null &&  _listKey.currentState.widget.initialItemCount < messageList.length)` and post the result?

Comment: I can't print the updateList before its declared. However printing the mesageList before the if-statement results in this: [Instance of 'Message', ... , Instance of 'Message'] and if I print the updateList right after it is declared (inside the if-statement) I get the same thing except that messageList.length = 26 and updatedList.length = 27.

Comment: I think the equality check for the `Message` object for the `updateList` is failing to identify similar objects.
You'll need to override the equality operator. Please update your question with your `Message` class.

Comment: I think you are right. I have now updated it. I could alternatively add an id to the message class that is the document id of the firestore document. The uid that is currently associated is the userid of the person that sent the message.

Comment: Yeah you can add a message-id using the document id. I'll update my answer with an update to the Message class shortly.

Comment: I've added the update. Please, check it out @TobiasSvendsen

Comment: Thanks! It works as intended now. Didn't know dart required you to go through such hoops to make custom objects comparable. Really appreciate your help!

Comment: Glad to help! You can check these documentation links for more information on this: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.3/dart-core/Object/operator_equals.html, https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/library-tour#implementing-map-keys, https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.3/dart-core/Object/hashCode.html. :)

Comment: This code helped me very much, but I also need to animate on removing object from a list. How to do this?

Comment: HI @John, please open a new question with your current code and post the link here.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an abstraction that I am using to animate a list of tasks - it uses SliverAnimatedList but you can adapt that for a regular animated list:

```dart
// if you had a class for your list data like 
class MyItem {
  const MyItem({ required this.id, required this.name });
  final String id;
  final String name;
}


// then your build method could be like this
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

  return StreamSliverAnimatedListBuilder<MyItem>(
    stream: _loadData(), 
    build: (context, item, animation) {
      return FadeTransition(
        opacity: animation,
        child: SizeTransition(
          sizeFactor: animation,
          child: ListTile(title: Text(item.name)),
        ),
      );
    },
    compare: (p0, p1) => p0.id == p1.id
  );
}
```

Widget code

```dart
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class StreamSliverAnimatedListBuilder<T> extends StatefulWidget {
  const StreamSliverAnimatedListBuilder(
      {super.key,
      required this.stream,
      required this.build,
      required this.compare,
      this.fallback});

  final Stream<List<T>> stream;
  final Widget Function(
      BuildContext context, T item, Animation<double> animation) build;
  final bool Function(T, T) compare;
  final Widget? fallback;

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _StreamSliverAnimatedListBuilderState<T>();
  }
}

class _StreamSliverAnimatedListBuilderState<T>
    extends State<StreamSliverAnimatedListBuilder<T>> {
  late final GlobalObjectKey<SliverAnimatedListState> _listKey =
      GlobalObjectKey<SliverAnimatedListState>(this);

  List<T> _currentList = [];
  bool _hasData = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    widget.stream.listen((event) {
      final List<T> newList = event;

      if (_hasData && _listKey.currentState != null) {
        List<T> addedItems = newList
            .where((a) => !_currentList.any((b) => widget.compare(a, b)))
            .toList();

        for (var update in addedItems) {
          final int updateIndex = newList.indexOf(update);
          _listKey.currentState!.insertItem(updateIndex);
        }

        List<T> removedItems = _currentList
            .where((a) => !newList.any((b) => widget.compare(a, b)))
            .toList();

        for (var update in removedItems) {
          final int updateIndex = _currentList.indexOf(update);
          _listKey.currentState!.removeItem(updateIndex, (context, animation) {
            return widget.build(context, update, animation);
          });
        }
      }

      _currentList = newList;
      if (!_hasData) {
        setState(() {
          _hasData = true;
        });
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (!_hasData) {
      return SliverToBoxAdapter(child: widget.fallback);
    }

    return SliverAnimatedList(
      key: _listKey,
      initialItemCount: _currentList.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index, animation) {
        if (_currentList.length <= index) {
          return Text('what. $index');
        }

        final item = _currentList[index];
        return widget.build(context, item, animation);
      },
    );
  }
}
```