# Flutter: How to make an animated list with firestore snapshots stream

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a page which gets data from a firestore stream. The problem is that I am using a StreamBuilder to get the data so the widget just rebuilds whenever the stream changes values. How can I get the changes to use an animated list and insert/remove items?

Comment: Please post the current code.

Comment: Also, check if this helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67935657/11039164

Comment: @VictorEronmosele Seems like that would work. Thanks!